# ODT file support on the iPhone app?

Tags: files, iphone

I noticed that only doc and docx files can be viewed in the Ubuntu One app for the iPhone.  Is there are plans to support odt files?  I like to use the default libreoffice file structure.  I bet many Ubuntu users feel the same.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can install the "OOReader" free application on your iPhone. When you select an openoffice file from ubuntuone, it will give you the choice to use OOReader to open it: instead of clicking on "View", click on the arrow icon in the bottom right corner of the page then select "OOReader"